# Avoiding compiler issues with abs()

Tags: c++

When using the `double` variant of the `std::abs()` function without the `std` with g++ 4.6.1, no warning or error is given.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

double foobar(double a)
{
     return abs(a);
}
```

This version of g++ seems to be pulling in the `double` variant of `abs()` into the global namespace through one of the includes from `algorithm`. This looks like it is now allowed by the standard (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405887/when-the-c-standard-provides-c-headers-bringing-names-into-the-global-namespac)), but not required.

If I compile the above code using a compiler that does not pull the `double` variant of `abs()` into the global namespace (such as g++ 4.2), then the following error is reported:

```
warning: passing 'double' for argument 1 to 'int abs(int)'
```

How can I force g++ 4.6.1, and other compilers that pull functions into the global namespace, to give a warning so that I can prevent errors when used with other compilers?

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::abs` if that is the function you need?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nothing, but it can be easy to miss out by mistake. I don't want that slip to go undetected and cause compilation issues with other compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function you are using is actually the integer version of `abs`, and GCC does an implicit conversion to integer.

This can be verified by a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double a = -5.4321;
    double b = std::abs(a);
    double c = abs(a);

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << '\n';
}
```

Output is:

```
a = -5.4321, b = 5.4321, c = 5
```

To get a warning about this, use the `-Wconversion` flag to g++. Actually, the GCC documentation for that option explicitly mentions calling `abs` when the argument is a `double`. All warning options can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: @SamDeHaan Sorry, updated result but forgot to update the code. :)

Comment: Is it the standard that has changed or a change in g++'s implementation that causes the implicit conversion with 4.6.1 and not 4.2? Are both valid?

Comment: The above code doesn't compile with my version of g++ (4.4.2).  If I add an `#include <math.h>` it will, however.  And VC++ (VS 2010) calls the double version of `abs`.  (I think this is actually the point of the original posting.  The behavior is very varied.)  Formally, it shouldn't compile in C++03; whether it compiles in C++11 is implementation defined.  In practice, however, there's always been a great deal of variation across implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Be warned, you don't need to explicitly `#include <cmath>`, `<iostream>` does the damage as well (and maybe some other headers).  Also, note that `-Wall` doesn't give you any warnings about it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << abs(.5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(decltype(abs)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Gives output

```
0
FiiE
```

On

```
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)
```