# abs vs std::abs, what does the reference say?

Tags: c++, cmath

Beware, I am talking about `::abs()`, not `std::abs()`

According to the [cplusplus.com website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/), `abs` is supposed to behave differently for the `stdlib.`h C version, if you include `<cmath>`

Here is an extract from the this page (which deals with `::abs`, not `std::abs`):

```
double abs (double x); 
float abs (float x); 
long double abs (long double x);
Compute absolute value
/*
Returns the absolute value of x: |x|.
These convenience abs overloads are exclusive of C++. In C, abs is only declared
in  <cstdlib> (and operates on int values). 
The additional overloads are provided in this header (<cmath>) for the integral types: 
These overloads effectively cast x to a double before calculations 
(defined for T being any integral type).
*/
```

*Really???*

I have been bitten by this when porting a program to a new platform, since different compilers and standard libraries implementation differ here.

Here is my sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <stdlib.h>//Necessary inclusion compil under linux
//You can include either cmath or math.h, the result is the same
//#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  double x = -1.5;
  double ax = std::abs(x);
  std::cout << "x=" << x << " ax=" << ax << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the result under MSVC 2010:

- No compilation warning is emitted under MSVC 2010, and the program will compile even if you do not include neither math.h nor `stdlib.h`: it seems like `math.h` and `stdlib.h` are always included whatever you do
- The program output is: `x=-1.5 ax=1.5` (seemingly correct according to the reference)

Now here is the result under OSX:

- No compilation warning is emitted, even with the `-Wall` flag (the double to int cast is not signaled)! The result is the same if you replace `g++` by `llvm-g++`. The inclusion of `math.h` or `cmath` is not required for the compilation.
- The program output is: `x=-1.5 ax=1`

And finally the result under Linux:

- The program will not compile if `stdlib.h` is not included (at last, one compiler that does not include `stdlib` automatically). No compilation warning is emitted for the double -> int cast.
- The program output is: `x=-1.5 ax=1`

No clear winner here. I know that an obvious answer is "prefer `std::abs` to `::abs`", but I wonder:

- Is the cplusplus.com website right here when it says that `abs` should automatically provide double version outside of the `std` namespace?
- Are all compiler and their standard libraries wrong here except MSVC (although it includes `math.h` silently)?

Comment: `cstdlib` is not a C header, so cplusplus.com is wrong there (surprise surprise). Also note that including `iostream` can confuse things, because it can include `cmath` and/or `cstdlib`, both of which may introduce various `abs` overloads in the global namespace. So get rid of that.

Comment: Hang on; are we using `std::abs` or just `::abs`?  (Using MinGW, the above complains that `'abs' is not a member of 'std'`; changing to `::abs` gives me the 1 result.

Comment: "the double to int cast is not signaled" - there's no double to int cast in your code. "Is cplusplus.com right" - **I don't know,** but cplusplus.com is *notorious* for containing incorrect and/or misleading information, so my guess would be "no, cplusplus.com is wrong". The same applies to MSVC (if 3 compilers agree and MSVC disagrees, then it's very likely that MSVC is wrong, but again, I don't know, I'm not a C++ programmer.)

Comment: cplusplus.com is such a terrible resource.  There is no `<cstdlib>` in the C standard.  To say "in C, abs is only declared in <cstdlib>" is just wrong.

Comment: I will have learned that cplusplus.com is not a precise enough resource, thanks !

Comment: “which deals with `::abs`, not `std::abs`” – uh, how did you figure that out?

Comment: cplusplus.com may be somewhat imprecise, but I have yet to see a statement that's explicitly wrong on it. It's by no means a terrible resource.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/abs/ and I (wrongly ?) inferred that there was a "std::" before functions in the std namespace

Comment: @AdamS "In C, abs is only declared in <cstdlib>..." That is explicitly wrong, and is linked in the question, and a source of part of the confusion.

Comment: @tabstop : yes, were are at the bare abs outside of the std namespace

Comment: @juanchopanza While <cstdlib> is a link to a page that mentions stdlib.h. Reading the "C library" section page, it's explicitly stated: _"Each header file has the same name as the C language version but with a "c" prefix and no extension. For example, the C++ equivalent for the C language header file <stdlib.h> is <cstdlib>"_

Comment: Here are the correct references : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs and http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs

Comment: @AdamS The statement is still clearly wrong. `cstdlib` is not a C header. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @AdamS Note too that `<cmath>` doesn't have the same contents as `<math.c>` in C, and that `<math.h>` in C++ can differ subtly from `<math.h>` in C++ (and that pre-C++11, almost no compiler was conformant when it came to `<cmath>`).

Comment: Oh, I just spend an afternoon debugging program because it was using `abs` (`::abs`) instead of `fabs` or `std::abs`. Is there any compiler warning that can catch this?

Comment: Ansering myself, yes there is `-Wconversion` that will catch exactly this, that is the implicit conversion of `double` to `int` in `abs(d)`. Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9066697/225186

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The official references say... it's a mess.  Pre-C++11 and C11:

- Officially, including `<cmath>` introduced nothing in `::`;
  all of the functions were in `std::`.  Practically, only
  `export` was less respected, and different compilers did very
  different things.  If you included `<cmath>`, you used `std::`
  everywhere, or what you got varied from compiler to compiler.
- C didn't provide any overloads: `abs` took an `int`, and was
  declared in `<stdlib.h>`, `fabs` took `double`, and was
  declared in `<math.h>`.
- If you included `<math.h>` in C++, it's not clear what you
  got, but since none of the implementers seemed to care about
  the standard anyway (see the first point above)...

Roughly speaking, either you included `<cmath>`, and prefixed
all of the uses with `std::`, or you included `<math.h>`, and
used `fabs` if you wanted support for floating point (and the
various suffixes for types other than `int` or `double`).

C++11 and C11 added a few new twists:

- `<cmath>` is now allowed (but not required) to introduce the
  symbols in `::` as well.  One more thing which can vary
  depending on the implementation.  (The goal here was to make
  existing implementations conformant.)
- C has a new header, `<tgmath.h>`, which uses compiler magic to
  make the functions in `<math.h>` behave as if they were
  overloaded as in C++.  (So it doesn't apply to `abs`, but only
  to `fabs`.)  This header had *not* been added to C++, for the
  obvious reason that C++ doesn't need any compiler magic for
  this.

All in all, the situation has become slightly worse, and my
recommendations above still hold.  Include either `<math.h>` and
`<stdlib.h>`, and use `abs`/`fabs` and their derivated (e.g.
`labs`, `fabsf`, etc.) exclusively, or include `<cmath>`, and
use `std::abs` exclusively.  Anything else, and you'll run into
portabiity problems.

Comment: You are right, it's a mess :-) But many thanks for your detailed answer and for the account of the C/C++ history

Comment: Excellent answer.  One that confirms my discover after debugging why code that worked perfectly on a Visual Studio compiled application that computed differences between very similar angles was working, but when the code was ported to linux/gcc suddenly the answer changed.

From a c++ perspective of class design (and ignoring the backwards compatibility issue), the expectation that  you get abs(<type> x) can really bit you, because it all works till suddenly it doesn't.  So to be safe you need to explicitly say which one you want: abs() fabs() or std::abs()  <facepalm>

Answer (score 0):

I was stucked by this bug for half day!!!
I use abs(a double value) in my code. but the result wasn't what expected. Until I change abs to std::abs(the double value above). All results match.