# How to do ray plane intersection?

Tags: c++, raycasting, raytracing

How do I calculate the intersection between a ray and a plane?

## Code

This produces the wrong results.

```
float denom = normal.dot(ray.direction);

if (denom > 0)
{
    float t = -((center - ray.origin).dot(normal)) / denom;

    if (t >= 0)
    {
        rec.tHit = t;
        rec.anyHit = true;
        computeSurfaceHitFields(ray, rec);
        return true;
    }
}
```

## Parameters

`ray` represents the ray object.
`ray.direction` is the direction vector.
`ray.origin` is the origin vector.
`rec` represents the result object.
`rec.tHit` is the value of the hit.
`rec.anyHit` is a boolean.

My function has access to the plane:
`center` and `normal` defines the plane

Comment: When you say this does not work, what specifically isn't working? Is it crashing, are the results wrong? does it fail to compile?

Comment: Is your normal vector guaranteed to point away from the ray origin? Otherwise, *denom < 0* might very well still produce an intersection.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As wonce commented, you want to also allow the denominator to be negative, otherwise you will miss intersections with the front face of your plane. However, you still want a test to avoid a division by zero, which would indicate the ray being parallel to the plane. You also have a superfluous negation in your computation of `t`. Overall, it should look like this:

```
float denom = normal.dot(ray.direction);
if (abs(denom) > 0.0001f) // your favorite epsilon
{
    float t = (center - ray.origin).dot(normal) / denom;
    if (t >= 0) return true; // you might want to allow an epsilon here too
}
return false;
```

Comment: What is center and what is ray origin?

Comment: `center` here is a known point on the plane. This uses the "Point-normal" description for the plane.

Comment: I have to point out that you should use `fabs()` and not `abs()` because `abs()` converts the input parameter to `int`.

Comment: @Duckdoom5: I was obviously talking about C++, because the question is tagged as C++. I assume you are talking about `std::abs()` (which has different overloads) and not `abs()` (which only deals with integers). Since the answer contains `abs()` instead of `std::abs()` and doesn't use a `using` directive either, I assume this to be a mistake. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392627/abs-vs-stdabs-what-does-the-reference-say

Comment: @Duckdoom5 I hope you'll delete that comment.  It's wrong and you'll confuse novices with wrong information.

Comment: @GlennMaynard You are right, I was assuming `std::abs()` was used here, so I'll delete the comment.

Comment: I used this code and it works fine. Math explanation: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm and t is the distance from ray to plane.

Comment: Are there no bounds to the plane? I don't understand where its size is determined.

Answer (score 8):

First consider the math of the ray-plane intersection:

In general one intersects the parametric form of the ray, with the implicit form of the geometry.

So given a ray of the form x = a * t + a0, y = b * t + b0, z = c * t + c0;

and a plane of the form: A x * B y * C z + D = 0;

now substitute the x, y and z ray equations into the plane equation and you will get a polynomial in t. you then solve that polynomial for the real values of t. With those values of t you can back substitute into the ray equation to get the real values of x, y and z.
Here it is in Maxima:

[image]

Note that the answer looks like the quotient of two dot products!
The normal to a plane is the first three coefficients of the plane equation A, B, and C.
You still need D to uniquely determine the plane.
Then you code that up in the language of your choice like so:

```
Point3D intersectRayPlane(Ray ray, Plane plane)
{
    Point3D point3D;

    //  Do the dot products and find t > epsilon that provides intersection.


    return (point3D);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find more on the implicit formula for a ray. What do a, t, and a0 represent in x(t)? Thank you!

Comment: The ray is in parametric form, whilst the plane is implicit form.
See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC427/RayTracing.pdf

Comment: That `-` sign next to the `t = ` is nearly invisible.

Answer (score 6):

### Math

Define:

- Let the ray be given parametrically by `q = p + t*v` for initial point `p` and direction vector `v` for `t >= 0`.
- Let the plane be the set of points `r` satisfying the equation `dot(n, r) + d = 0` for normal vector `n = (a, b, c)` and constant `d`. Fully expanded, the plane equation may also be written in the familiar form `ax + by + cz + d = 0`.

The ray-plane intersection occurs when `q` satisfies the plane equation. Substituting, we have:

```
d = -dot(n, q)
  = -dot(n, p + t * v)
  = -dot(n, p) + t * dot(n, v)
```

Rearranging:

```
t = -(dot(n, p) + d) / dot(n, v)
```

This value of `t` can be used to determine the intersection by plugging it back into `p + t*v`.

### Example implementation

```
std::optional<vec3> intersectRayWithPlane(
    vec3 p, vec3 v,  // ray
    vec3 n, float d  // plane
) {
    float denom = dot(n, v);

    // Prevent divide by zero:
    if (abs(denom) <= 1e-4f)
        return std::nullopt;

    // If you want to ensure the ray reflects off only
    // the "top" half of the plane, use this instead:
    //
    // if (-denom <= 1e-4f)
    //     return std::nullopt;

    float t = -(dot(n, p) + d) / dot(n, v);

    // Use pointy end of the ray.
    // It is technically correct to compare t < 0,
    // but that may be undesirable in a raytracer.
    if (t <= 1e-4)
        return std::nullopt;

    return p + t * v;
}
```

Comment: I wrote this answer to provide a complete working example for the `ax + by + cz + d = 0` form. Additionally discusses what to do if we only wish to reflect rays off a normally oriented plane (i.e. the front side of the plane... not its back).

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435512/snells-law-in-vector-form/436252#436252) for a derivation of Snell's Law in vector form, and its solution for the parameter `t`.

Comment: t = - (dot(n, p) + d) / dot(n, v)

should be

t = - (dot(n, p0) + d) / dot(n, v)

Answer (score 4):

implementation of vwvan's answer

```
Vector3 Intersect(Vector3 planeP, Vector3 planeN, Vector3 rayP, Vector3 rayD)
{
    var d = Vector3.Dot(planeP, -planeN);
    var t = -(d + Vector3.Dot(rayP, planeN)) / Vector3.Dot(rayD, planeN);
    return rayP + t * rayD;
}
```

Comment: Why did you write the two dot products in full in the $t$ calculation instead of calling $Vector3.Dot(rayP, planeN)$?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat I was busy the past four years :D