# Getting all ray intersections instead of only the first one

Tags: javascript, 3d, x3dom

I am using the X3DOM library for JavaScript. With the function `X3DOM.runtime.shootray(x, y)` it is possible to receive the first object that the ray hits and the coordinates of the spot. The problem is, all my objects are placed on a plane ("floor") and I need the intersection point between the ray and the floor rather than with the objects on it.

[image: Intersection]

Any solution idea? Some of my ideas were:

- Let the ray go all the way and receive all intersections rather than stopping on the first hit object
- Make the ray somehow pass through the objects and hit the floor (make the objects "invisible")

But I couldn't find any way to accomplish any of this. I'd be thankful for a bit of help.

Comment: If the floor is a fixed plane then you can use some vector math to compute the intersection  directly

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I have absolutely no idea how to do it!

Comment: There are plenty of results for "Ray-plane intersection". A good example on SO is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975555/how-to-do-ray-plane-intersection