# Finding the length of a ray intersecting with an infinite plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, post-processing

I am trying to use a post processing shader to create bodies of water. The water level will be at y = 0 and anything underneath that boundary will be affected by the shader. I will cast rays out from the camera position in the shader and retrieve the distance from the ground of each ray. I will then use that information to calculate how much water you are seeing through in order to calculate the color of the surface.The problem is I have no idea how to detect and calculate the distance travelled by the ray before intersecting with y = 0. Is there any way for me to achieve this effect.

**Failed Code**

```
float rayGroundIntersect(float3 rayOrigin, float3 rayDir) {
    if (rayDir.y <= 0) {
        return maxFloat;
    }
    float a = rayOrigin.y / rayDir.y;
    float l = length(rayDir.xz * a);
    return l;
}
```

A similar successful [project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lctXaT9pxA0) but on a sphere.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Comment: Your answer worked great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976134/1092820) by [Trillian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64885/trillian)

```
float rayGroundIntersect(float3 rayOrigin, float3 rayDir) {
    float denom = dot(float3(0,1,0), rayDir);
    if (abs(denom) > 0.0001f)
    {
        // negate normal instead of rayOrigin
        float t = dot(rayOrigin, float3(0,-1,0)) / denom; 
        return t >= 0 ? t : maxFloat;
    }
    return maxFloat;
}
```