# Why is `abs()` implemented differently?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang

I've had a super frustrating bug in my code for the past few weeks. My code would work exactly as expected on my computer, but as soon as I farmed it out to the HPC server, it would produce weird results.

I've boiled it down to this: on my computer (iMac) the function `abs()` works with floating point numbers, but on the server `abs()` truncates it to an integer.

Example:

Server

```
abs(-1.1341234) = 1
```

My Mac

```
abs(-1.1341234) = 1.1341234
```

Now I know I can fix this by using `fabs()`, that's not the question. I looked at the versions of `gcc` on either machine and this is the output:

Server

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/apps/software/GCCcore/5.4.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.4.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-lto --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-shared=yes --enable-static=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-gold=default --enable-plugins --enable-ld --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --prefix=/apps/software/GCCcore/5.4.0 --with-local-prefix=/apps/software/GCCcore/5.4.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-isl=/dev/shm/GCCcore/5.4.0/dummy-/gcc-5.4.0/stage2_stuff
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC)
```

My Mac

```
g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

So my question, why does `abs()` produce different results between gcc and clang? This issue literally cost me 3 weeks of progress, so as you can imagine I'm a little salty just now...

Comment: _so as you can imagine I'm a little salty just now..._ Annoying but worth the lecture... This will make you very sensitive about these things. ;-) (I don't mean this offensive but rather as a "heads up". Every really annoying bug might at least produce a valuable experience. So, take it positively...)

Comment: @Scheff Oh man, I certainly won't ever forget this lesson...

Comment: @Phill I have collected some of them in my mind ...and sometimes tell my colleagues my stories of old about this... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff **No**. A *good programming language* should not have such quirks. (There's *still* a lesson to be learned here, but I won't tell which one ;-) )

Comment: related: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

Comment: `-Wall`, fix all warnings. Always.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You *must* use `std::abs`, which has overloads for the primitive types.

You are falling through to the C++ version in one case, and the old C version (which converts its parameters to integral types) in the other.

Things to avoid: (1) `using namespace std;` ([here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/7478597)) and (2) not having the appropriate `#include`s to bring in the functionality you need. *Don't* rely on C++ standard library implementations to include files for you implicitly.

Some compilers will warn you of a "lossy" conversion if you set the warning level appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean with "you _must_ use `std::abs`"? Using `fabs` is also fine, isn't it?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler: That kicks the can down the road - fabs breaks for `long double` for example.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler if you are using c++ there is normally no good reason not to use the c++ version of the functions. Keep C to C and C++ to C++.

Comment: Thank you both. I have been using `fabs` for a long time. The advantage of `std::abs` is indeed something I haven't been aware of.

Comment: Correction: Use `fabs` instead of `abs` OR `std::abs` which is a template function.

Comment: *All* compilers should warn you of a floating-point to integer, or integer to floating-point, conversion. If your compiler doesn't, and you can't adjust its warning levels accordingly, discard it immediately and get yourself a better compiler.

Comment: Also know that unfortunately, this is a long-known issue. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392627/abs-vs-stdabs-what-does-the-reference-say from five years ago. That discussion already pointed out the ambiguity of ::abs and ::std::abs, that different compilers behave differently, and that none of them warn you that something fishy is going on.

Comment: @Rakete1111: It's lossy in full generality. E.g. 64 bit `int`, and IEEE754 `double`.