# Why doesn't std::abs() works with floats

Tags: c++, floating-point, std, absolute-value

The result of `std::abs(0.5f)` is `0` because there is no overload for floats. Why? I'm using G++.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.  I was unable to reproduce the misbehavior you ran into.

Comment: @Eljay It's my mistake, I talked about `abs()`, but wrote `std::abs()`, because I thought that they are the same things.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I've made that mistake before.  It is one of the reasons I created my *deader files*, which are fake C++ header files that define only the symbols required by the standard and nothing else and do not include any of the other header files.  (They compile, but they won't link, and they are effectively non-functional for purposes other than compiling and sanity checking and helping with "include what you use".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to be *very* careful when using the overloads of `std::abs` as some standard library implementations litter the overloads across many files, some of which get implicitly included into others, like `<iostream>`.

If you `#include <cmath>` or `#include <cstdlib>` (the second one from C++17) *before* your `std::abs(0.5f)` then the `float` overload will be available. If that's not the case, then there is a bug in your compiler / standard library implementation (unlikely in the case of g++).

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs

Comment: And there are two different funcs - `abs` and `std::abs`? And they have different overloads?

Comment: @Gordem: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392627/abs-vs-stdabs-what-does-the-reference-say. It's an absolute mess. I even have a rule for this in my shop: `#include <cmath>` and only ever use `std::<something or other>`.

Comment: I. e., this mess concerns not only `abs()`?

Comment: @Gordem There are other unrelated [messes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004858/why-is-stdmin-failing-when-windows-h-is-included), I'm afraid.