# Equation with abs() gives wrong answer (gcc/g++)

Tags: c++

Somehow I get wrong result from equation which involves library function abs().
Here's my code where the issue is present:

main.cpp  -------------------------------------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "test999.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n = 11;
    ak r;

    r = test(n);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("r.yp[%d] = %3.7f \n", i, r.yp[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

test999.h ---------------------------------------

```
struct ak{
    float yp[20];
};

ak test(int n){

    float u[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 4.5, 35, 10, 25, 40, 55};
    ak r;
    float a, b;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       a = abs(u[i+3] - u[i+2]);
       b = abs(u[i+1] - u[i]);

       printf("i = %d   a = u[%d](%2.4f) - u[%d](%2.4f) = %2.4f \n        b = u[%d]-u[%d] = %2.4f (%2.4f - %2.4f) \n", i, i+3, u[i+3], i+2, u[i+2], a, i+1,  u[i+1], i, u[i], b);

       if ((a+b) != 0.0f){
          r.yp[i] = (a * u[i+1] + b * u[i+2]) / (a+b);
       }
       else{
          r.yp[i] = (u[i+2] + u[i+1]) / 2.0f;
       }
       printf("yp[%d] = %2.4f \n\n", i, r.yp[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

and it results wrong value for equation of abs(0.5)-0.0 (case i=4) and abs(35.0)-4.5 (case i=6):

[image]

Changing equation to use std::abs() calculates correctly:

[image]

If I move everything to main.cpp module both cases works so, is it just that because of I have made defect code ... or rounding from 0.5 to 0.0 happened somewhere I should have taken into account... ?

Comment: So this is going to sound stupid... but you have a lot of unintended conversion going on in your code. `4.5` is a `double` not a `float`, ditto `1` is an integer. If you want to keep conversion to a minimum I'd suggest suffixing those with `f` to tell the compiler to make them float constants.

Comment: Replace `abs` with `std::abs`.  Still have the problem?

Comment: somewhat related: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21393170/580083). Relevant quote: _"C didn't provide any overloads: `abs` took an `int`, and was declared in `<stdlib.h>`"_. Without `std`, it seems that this "C" version is called and rounding occurs.

Comment: This is such a good example of why, even using it in a limited scope, using namespace std is a bad idea.

Comment: @user438383 the common mantra is "never in headers, can be ok in source", this is a nice counter example

Comment: @Mgetz yes, I forgot to edit those values to floats (copied from Octave output box) but result is same even with all set floats.

Comment: @Eijay latter result data shows for std::abs().

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, int-int and float-float pairs are OK but float-int and int-float pairs gets rounded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `std::abs(int)` and there is `std::abs(float)`. The former is inherited from C `abs(int)`. In C there is no overload for floating points, it is called `fabs` (also available as `std::fabs`).

You tripped over `using namespace std;` obfuscating what function is actually called. Note that you have it in `main`, but not in the header, which is actually good, but it still does harm in `main`, because once you place all code in `main`, suddenly a different function gets called. Without `using namespace std;`, `abs(some_float)` calls `::abs(int)`. With `using namespace std;`, `abs(some_float)` calls `std::abs(float)`.

Note that the headers inherited from C are allowed but not guaranteed to introduce the names in the global namespace, so you could also get a compiler error.

Replace `abs` with `std::abs` and remove `using namespace std`. For more reasons to not pull in all names from `std` I refer you to [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: In addition, when `using namespace std` is given already before `#include "test999.h"` in main module, inheritance is correct and abs() works properly. `#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#include "test999.h"

int main(){...}
`