# building a mixed c/c++ code

Tags: c++, c

I have a `.cc` file which uses both `iostream` and `malloc`. How can I compile that? using `g++`, it says

```
 error: 'malloc' was not declared in this scope
```

using `gcc`, it says

```
 fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
```

The source code is located at http://sequitur.info/sequitur_simple.cc

**UPDATE**

I changed `malloc` to `new` and chaned `free` to `delete`. Still I get a lot of errors. For example

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/new:103:14: error:   initializing argument 2 of âvoid* operator new(std::size_t, void*)â [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: You have to `#include` the appropriate file.

Comment: `malloc` is valid c++

Comment: Can you build the source code?

Comment: @KarthikT, but its not a good idea to mix

Comment: yep `#include`ing `<stdlib.h>` helps, also go for `<string.h>` as you're using `memset()`. I compiled the code doing those mods.

Comment: @hroptatyr, no include <cstring> if you must.  Don't mix C++ and C headers, it will cause all sorts of grief.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either include `<stdlib.h>` or include `<cstdlib>` and change `malloc` to `std::malloc` - compile with `g++`. Including `<cstdlib>` is the **prefered way** for new C++ code, "name.h" style is deprecated in C++.

While this will fix you problem, it might be a **better idea to migrate to `new`/`delete`**, to be more consistantly C++.

Comment: @mahmood Just noticed that, it does not include stdlib however, and that is the issue here.

Comment: @JoshPetitt the question is how to compile, and this answers it. There is no reason to downvote, if you wish to advocate new/delete you are welcome to answer it as well..

Comment: @KarthikT, it might answer it but it is not the "right" answer, please remove the .h include and only show the <cstdlib> and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @JoshPetitt it is a valid fix, and I would rather leave it in for completeness, especially since with the `using namespace std;` statement, both are all but identical. Unless you can give a concrete reason. I have already added guidelines to my answer.

Comment: @KarthikT I don't know if it matters with gcc, but MSVC++ it did matter and if you used both, there would be problems when linking to the standard lib. (probably bad example to use MSVC++ since it doesn't really support C that well) [why do some includes need the h and others do not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404725/why-do-some-includes-need-the-h-and-others-not)

Comment: Yes. But please let me write a new question. The thread will be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and use g++?

Answer (score 0):

use new and delete in C++ code.  Don't mix new and malloc.  From the code you posted, there isn't any reason AFAIK you can't use new and delete

Comment: Yes to prefer `new`/`delete` in C++ code, but mixing `new` and `malloc` is perfectly valid, won't confuse memory managers, and in some edge cases may be desirable.