# Typecasting malloc C++

Tags: c++, c, casting, malloc

I have some C code with malloc statements in it that I want to merge with some C++ code.

I was wondering when and why is typecasting a call to malloc neccessary in C++?

For example:

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1]) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018011/building-a-mixed-c-c-code/15018044#comment21100758_15018044

Comment: I saw that question already, but it doesn't answer why it's necessary in C++

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> when and why is typecasting a call to malloc neccessary in C++?

Always when not assigning to a `void *`, since `void *` doesn't convert implicitly to other pointer types, the way it does in C. But the true answer is **you shouldn't ever use `malloc` in C++** in the first place.

---

I am not suggesting you should use `new` instead of `malloc`. Modern C++ code should use `new` sparingly, or avoid it altogether if possible. You should hide all use of `new` or use non-primitive types (like `std::vector` mentioned by Xeo). I'm not really qualified to give advice in this direction due to my limited experience but [this article](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/c++-new.html) along with searching for "C++ avoid new" should help. Then you'll want to look into:

- [std::alocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)
- Smart pointers

Comment: "Ever" is so strong..

Comment: @Inisheer It is, but by removing it I would feel like weaseling out.

Comment: @Inisheer: It's not only strong, it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: Btw, maybe you should give some advice as what to use *instead* (hint: `std::vector` and friends).

Comment: Why is using malloc in C++ so bad?  This was originally intended to be a purely C program, until I needed to merge in some C++ code.  It would be a hassle to convert all those `malloc`s to `new`s

Comment: It's bad because it doesn't construct objects. And also because it shares every bad that `new` has, which are *MANY*.

Comment: @Xeo, DeadMG You're probably better suited for explaining how one should avoid `new`.

Comment: @cnicutar some people would argue against you, but I agree. [see question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018011/building-a-mixed-c-c-code/15018044)

Answer (score 2):

Compile your C library.  Compile your C++ library.  Make them play nice in whatever "main" program that uses them.  Point is if your maintaining a mixed code base, you probably want to isolate the pure C stuff from the C++ stuff.  Otherwise your C stuff turns into C++ stuff that only looks like C.

Answer (score 1):

First, in almost all circumstances just don't use `malloc` in a C++ program, but prefer `new` instead because it will make sure that constructors are called when needed, etc.

However if for legacy reasons you're trying to avoid as much rewrite as possible - you'll need to cast *any* `malloc` call that's not assigned to a `void*` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change that code its probably better to use `new` instead so it would look like this

`char* str = new char;`

this means you don't need to do any casting like the C way and you don't need to specify how large the memory you need. Also if this was an object like a `std::string` then you WILL not call the constructor when you use `malloc`, this merely reserves the memory for use with the pointer `str` so best always use `new` with C++ if you can also when you reclaim memory always use the appropriate way, if you `new` then you `delete` and if you `malloc` you `free`. If you use `free` on memory that has been `new`'d then you won't call that objects destructor.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` always returns a `void*` so you need to cast everything (because C++ has stronger type checking than C and don't this automatically)

When I am using C, I also cast everything, for code clarity.

Also, feel free to keep using `malloc()` in C++, it is there for a good reason.

Converting all the C code to C++ by rewriting every single `malloc()` to new is very prone to introduce lots of errors in your code, unless you have the time to keep reading the code you are merging to find every single instance of `malloc()`, `free()`, `calloc()`, etc... on it.

Just don't mix `malloc()` with `delete` or `new` with `free()` or things break.

Comment: My approach is not using malloc

Comment: "When I am using C, I also cast everything, for code clarity." - Actually, [you cast it for ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). It is an **error** to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.

Comment: @speeder Well, about the `new` part... the really good C++ doesn't use `new` either

Comment: I have been doing it this way for years, from before I learned C++, because seriously, not casting to see if you get <stlib.h> is just silly. And unless you have crazy type names it won't make your code much longer.

Comment: @speeder But come on, casts are *ugly* and redundant. I rather read `int *ptr = malloc(size);` than `int *ptr = (int *)malloc(size);`.

Comment: `int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` might look redundant, but what if you end with `avarboPlex = malloc(MAXSIZEOFBO);` ?

Comment: That's the sign you should change language to C++