# Reading char to (char pointer)

Tags: c++, c

how would i convert this to return char* an not use std::string
just want to learn other ways to do this without std::string

```
string getName(DWORD Address)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address);

    int size = ReadCharSize();

    string name = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        char c = ReadCharArrayChar(i);
        name += c;
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: By looking at the documentation for `std:string`. Hint: .`c_str()` - you'll likely want the use of `strdup`, too

Comment: why you want to do that? If you're up to return a `char*` you have to allocate and later deallocate memory. Plus you have to keep in mind that C strings end up with `\0` null character. There's no reason to do this really.

Comment: what's with `ReadCharArrayChar[i]();`?

Comment: i didnt wanted to see other ways without std::string.
I just through this together its like something im doing so ReadCharArrayChar[i](); was just a example

Answer (score 4):

The other ways are ugly, which is one of the reasons `std::string` exists :). But for educational purposes, here is how you could return `char*` (as asked):

```
// caller is responsible for deleting the return value
char* getEntityName(DWORD Address)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address); // (not sure what this achieves)

    int size = ReadCharSize();

    char* name = new char[size];
    name[size - 1] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        char c = ReadCharArrayChar[i](); // odd looking, but I'll assume this works
        name[i] = c;
    }

    return name;
}
```

A similar option still uses a raw pointer for the buffer, but has the caller pass it in (along with its size):

```
// returns: true iff the buffer was successfully populated with the name
// exceptions might be a better choice, but let's keep things simple here
bool getEntityName(DWORD Address, char* buffer, int maxSize)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address); // (not sure what this achieves?)

    int size = ReadCharSize();
    if(size > maxSize)
       return false;

    buffer[size - 1] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        char c = ReadCharArrayChar[i](); // odd looking, but I'll assume this works
        buffer[i] = c;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The latter option would allow, for example:

```
char buffer[100];
getEntityName(getAddress(), buffer, 100);
```

Comment: dont you have to delete the new char[size]?

Comment: @Nathan The calling code will need to do that eventually.

Comment: Is that the best way to do it with std::string then?

Comment: @Nathan do you mean with*out* `std::string`? "Best" always depends on context, but it's probably what I'd do if I were forbidden from using any sort of string object. Another option would be to have the caller pass in a buffer and a max size. That would give you more flexibility in how and where the characters were stored.

Answer (score 2):

```
char * getEntityName(DWORD Address)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address);

    int size = ReadCharSize();

    char* name = malloc (size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        name[i] = ReadCharArrayChar[i]();
    }

    name[size - 1] = 0;

    return name;
}
```

Note that the caller should `free` the returned value when they're done with it. This assumes `size` includes the terminating zero byte, which it seems to given the example code.

Comment: Upvoted, but the result of the `malloc` will need to be explicitly cast to `char*`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @dlf `malloc` returns a `void *`, so no cast is necessary.

Comment: @FiddlingBits my compiler (VC2012) will not perform that cast implicitly. However, I've learned (here) that what my compiler will or won't do is not always the best barometer of correctness... :)

Comment: @FiddlingBits But maybe [this time it's right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e85764f44b394b2c)

Comment: @dlf Should have stopped being necessary when C99 was published... I think. :-D

Comment: @FiddlingBits From a quick survey of SO questions ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118990/typecasting-malloc-c), for example), it seems that it is necessary in C++, but not in C. The question is tagged with both languages (despite using `std::string` in the original), so I suppose there's no reason for me to complain.

Comment: @dlf You may be correct. I must admit, I'm a dunce when it comes to C++.

Answer (score 1):

If I absolutely could not use `std::string`, I would either use `std::vector<char>` for this:

```
std::vector<char> getName(DWORD Address)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address);

    const int size = ReadCharSize();

    std::vector<char> name(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        name[i] = ReadCharArrayChar(i);
    }

    name[size - 1] = '\0';

    return name;
}
```

or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` if I knew the caller would never need to modify the result:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> getName(DWORD Address)
{
    DWORD BaseDword = ReadBaseDword(Address);

    const int size = ReadCharSize();

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> name(new char[size]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        name[i] = ReadCharArrayChar(i);
    }

    name[size - 1] = '\0';

    return name;
}
```