# Why is it mandatory to explicitly typecast malloc and calloc in C++?

Tags: c++, malloc, calloc

I recently read an article which said it's not necessary in C to explicitly typecast malloc and calloc but in C++ it is mandatory. Why is it so? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typecasting malloc C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118990/typecasting-malloc-c)

Comment: I edited the tags because you are asking about C++ but in C there is: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) In C the received wisdom isn't just that it is unnecessary but *undesirable*.

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-need-to-typecast-a-malloc-returns-type).

Comment: Short answer, because `void *` in cpp doesn't convert implicitly, whereas in C it does. It's how language is designed.

Comment: @gst That really is about it.  OP then may ask "why was C++ designed that way?"  Then that's another question leading down some [rabbit hole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabbit%20hole).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's something I'd love to hear about as well!

Comment: Those are the rules of C++.   Those functions return a `void *`.  If it were possible, then you should be able to do something simple like this: `void *ptr = nullptr; char* a = ptr;`, but you get the same error without the cast.

Comment: @gst: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275712/why-arent-void-s-implicitly-cast-in-c/275714) and answers sort of address that

Answer (score 4):

Because in C it is very often you need to use `void *` for various cases. Some of them is a cookie for a callback - when you provide pointer to user data and you do not have a way to know that data type. Or generic functions like `qsort()` they have to work with various data without knowing their type in advance. In C++ though you do not need to use `void *` as often, and in good safe code you do not need to use them at all because you have templates so you write generic code using unknown types without unsafe conversions. So creators of C++ wanted to stimulate proper usage of data types and make sure when developer doing unsafe operations he/she/it/they understands what he/she/it/they is doing.

As `malloc()` and `calloc()` return `void *` you have to convert them explicitly in C++. Note that you are not suppose to use them in C++, but use `operator new` instead - which returns proper pointer type already and you do not need cast. And even further in modern C++ it is not recommended to even call `new` directly.

Comment: Love the answer! But could you edit it to use "she/he" or even "they" instead of just "he"? Even better, maybe rewrite it using "you"?

Comment: @gst sure, here you go

Answer (score 2):

In C, it's given `T *tp; U *up; void *vp;`, one can say `vp = tp; up = vp;` and end up with a `U*` which holds the address of a `T`, without using any casting operators.  The designers of C++, however, wanted to ensure that such a thing couldn't happen without using at least one explicit casting operator somewhere along the way.  In most cases, requiring the casting operator to be used between the time the pointer is represented as a `void*` and the time it's actually used is less of a nuisance than requiring a casting operator when a pointer is converted to `void*`, that's what C++ does.  Neither C or C++ allows any syntactic distinction between a `void*` which was produced by converting the address of an object with a real type, however, versus one that is used to hold the address of a blob of storage with no type, and thus has no way of allowing the latter to be implicitly converted to any type (which would be useful) without doing likewise with the former (which the designers of C++ didn't want).